# getting udid of android emulator

Tags: android

I want to get udid of android emulator..How can i get it.Has anyone implemented it before?

Comment: Please see this link.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468248/unique-id-of-android-device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468248/unique-id-of-android-device)

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can use TelephonyManager.getDeviceId() to get udid of a device, but if you are using Android emulator, it will return null. [Docs here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId%28%29)

Update:

You need to require READ_PHONE_STATE permission in your AndroidManifest.xml, i.e., by adding following line in the file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: You need to require READ_PHONE_STATE permission first, I've updated the answer.