# Why is a hardcoded UUID used in the Android Sample BluetoothChat application?

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid

Why hardcode instead of doing something like in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088474/how-can-i-get-the-uuid-of-my-android-phone-in-an-application)? And what is supposed to be the difference between the secure and insecure uuid?

 Heres a [link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/bluetoothchat/BluetoothChatService.java#L49-L53) to the BluetoothService class in which the code below resides.

```
// Unique UUID for this application
    private static final UUID MY_UUID_SECURE =
            UUID.fromString("fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66");
    private static final UUID MY_UUID_INSECURE =
            UUID.fromString("8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you provided gives an answer of how to find the device's id, the  [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088474/how-can-i-get-the-uuid-of-my-android-phone-in-an-application?answertab=active#tab-top) gets the [device id](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId()) ([IMEI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Station_Equipment_Identity), if a GSM phone), a per device unique identifier. This is not a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) it can be transformed into one but that does not solve the problem [Bluetooth Chat example application](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat/) presents. The key to understanding why Bluetooth Chat is using a static UUID is to understand [Bluetooth Service Discover Protocol](https://www.bluetooth.org/en-us/specification/assigned-numbers/service-discovery). UUID's in SDP declare what protocol or service is available and are well known. If random UUID's were used and no one shared their meaning other devices would not know how to interact with that Bluetooth Service. This is roughly similar to putting a random schema in a URI. For example browsers know `http` and `https` (`https` is understood to use TLS) but not `foop` or `barp`. And, to represent a specific device Bluetooth uses a [MAC Address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address), which is a 48-bit unique number.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. In the 2nd answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964342/android-how-do-bluetooth-uuids-work the user says you can use an arbitrary id from a generator if both applications are using the same protocol. Im confused by this since you say these UUIDs are meant to specify predetermined protocols.

Comment: Both applications would still be using the same UUID. Generating a UUID is a completely separate step.