# Under what conditions does android device UUID change?

Tags: android, uuid

I want to know on what conditions a device UUID changes? I heard it changes on factory resets and android upgrades, but I have not found any proof or documented sources.

Thanks,

Comment: What is your definition of device UUID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read here the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html?hl=es#ANDROID_ID)

> A 64-bit number (as a hex string) that is randomly generated when the user first sets up the device and should remain constant for the lifetime of the user's device. The value may change if a factory reset is performed on the device.

About UUID behaviour on Android update there isn't much documentation online, but you can check [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088474/how-can-i-get-the-uuid-of-my-android-phone-in-an-application#answer-5628136)

> - In some rare circumstances, this ID may change.  In particular, if the device is factory reset a new device ID
>
>   - may be generated.  In addition, if a user upgrades their phone from certain buggy implementations of Android 2.2
>   - to a newer, non-buggy version of Android, the device ID may change.  Or, if a user uninstalls your app on
>   - a device that has neither a proper Android ID nor a Device ID, this ID may change on reinstallation.

Comment: When i am getting UUID on Splash Screen, it is going to change on every launch of application. why is this?