# Best way to create unique id for server use in android app

Tags: android, unique, uniqueidentifier

I need a unique media id for each media which I will upload on a server in my app, because of some reason I need to create it from the Android side. Can anyone suggest any best way to achieve this?

Comment: better way than which way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the UUID of my Android phone in an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088474/how-can-i-get-the-uuid-of-my-android-phone-in-an-application)

Comment: This could help https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids

Comment: @Rohit5k2 sorry for a wrong word, I want to ask the best way, now I edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I find the solution,
I am using userId+System.currentTimeMillis() and create a unique code, it is unique for each media and also for each user.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate unique id using below code:

```
UUID.randomUUID().toString()
```

it will return a unique string.

Answer (score -1):

for unique Id use current Time in miliseconds

```
System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Comment: I thing this is the easiest solution for uniqueness

Comment: Easy doesn't mean correct. There is no guarantee of being milliseconds to be unique. What if another user takes the action at the exact same moment?

Comment: its in milliseconds so this will rarely happen and another one solution is by getting device id but what if he want to create multiple unique id then??

Comment: Seems you could use some read. https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids

Comment: if 2 persons are upload media in-app at the same time it will create the same media id.

Comment: I have another one solution. That is generate md5 code of currentTimeInMiliSeconds and your device id that will be always diffrent from others

Comment: You are funny. If a unit of time changes very fast that doesn't mean only one baby was born. :D

Comment: Instead of making joke give the solution

Comment: Just tell me how will you generate id at local that will remain unique at serverside