# How to get Unique ID of Android Device?

Tags: android, telecommunication, imei

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a unique Android device ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id)

I'm developing an application in which i want to map username with their mobile's unique id. Is there any method from which I get Unique ID for device.

I had go through getting IMEI no, but found that it can be changed.
Also gone through AndroidDevice ID, but it can also be changed.

Comment: Dear there are plenty of questions already exists on SO for the same functionality, i would request you to go through this Question first: [Is there a unique Android device ID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id)

Comment: Also visit this: [Unique ID of Android Device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468248/unique-id-of-android-device)