# is there any unique value on android, iphone, pc?

Tags: android, iphone, macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unique ID of Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468248/unique-id-of-android-device)

AFAIK, the emei number, mac address can be change by some hacking work. I am in need to find an unique value on each device which can not replace, cannot edit. Is there any value?

Comment: No downvote. Please search before posting new questions; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468248/unique-id-of-android-device

Comment: Hi, I am asking about unique value on various devices. Not android only. Please reopen my question for more discussion. Thanks.

Comment: I am thinking about GUID. We can generate a GUID number then save it at an encrypt file. Do you think this's good?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
String android_id = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

**NOTE: The emulator will return a NULL value so if you try to use this value in the emulator environment your application will crash.**

Comment: This is actually documented as potentially changing on a factory reset. And actually, can be changed at will with a custom ROM set up to do so. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID

Answer (score 0):

For Mac OSX you can use the command line:

`ioreg -rd1 -c IOPlatformExpertDevice | awk '/IOPlatformUUID/ { split($0, line, "\""); printf("%s\n", line[4]); }'`

Comment: Could this key be replaced by some hacking on Mac OSX?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this can't be changed.

Answer (score 0):

For phones or devices that carry a sim card, you can rely on the ICCID which is basically the serial number of the SIM. I have unheard of ways to hack the ICCID, so you can probably trust it.

Android allows you to fectch the ICCID through: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSimSerialNumber%28%29

Another option is the IMSI (corresponds to the subscription number), also available on android.

Comment: So, the ICCID may change when user insert another simcard. I mean, this not a unique value of device. It's a unique value of Sim card.

Comment: Yes. The issue is that an unique value of the device would consist of its serial number. However, there seems not to be much support to retrieve that from PCs. On phones, the only thing you have is the IMEI, which as you mentioned can be hacked and reprogrammed. In that point, the ICCID, has an advantage as it "cant" be reprogrammed. I guess for your this case there is no perfect solution and you will need to do a compromise in one side or the other

Comment: on PC I know that we can get mac address. It's a unique value (if it isn't hacked)

Comment: Yeah, but mac is not a very "reliable" as it can be hacked, desktops can have theirs network card changed and pcs may have more than one network card =D I guess it all boils down to the underlying requirements behind you need for uniqueness