# Can Asynctask be slowing down my UI?

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, android-asynctask

I'm creating an API for an app. When the app launches (`MainActivity.onCreate()`) an initialization call is made. This initialization causes the UI to lag for a second though, and I want to get rid of the lag. The sequence of (larger) events in the initialization call is as follows:

(1) `getDeviceID()` [generates a UID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10294536/2561963)

(2) `setBuild()` uses `StringBuilder` to append strings together and then sha1 it (code available upon request)

(3) create an instance of a subclassed [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) thread called `DopamineRequest`. This sends an HTTP request

(4) `getInitRequest()` creates a `JSONObject` by iterating through a couple of `LinkedHashSet<String>`s and also using `System.currentTimeMillis()`

(5) execute the AsyncTask thread which only has the `doInBackground()` function overridden

If I understand how AsyncTask works, it's executed in the background so should have no effect on the UI unless the UI calls asyncTask.get() which blocks it.

Is some other function causing the lag or is it AsyncTask?

```
protected static void initBase(Context c){
        if(context!=null)   // already been initialized
            return;

        context = c;
        if(identity == null) {
            identity = new HashMap<String, String>();
        }
        identity.put( "DEVICE_ID", getDeviceID() );           // (1)
        setBuild();                                           // (2)

        URIBuilder uri = new URIBuilder(appID);

        DopamineRequest initRequest = new DopamineRequest();  // (3)
        String initRequest = getInitRequest();                // (4)
        initRequest.execute(uri.getURI(URIBuilder.URI.INIT), initRequest) // (5);

    }
```

Comment: Use Traceview and figure out where your problem actually lies.

Comment: are you doing anything in your onPreExecute() because that is invoked in the UI thread.

Comment: It is almost certainly some other function. Besides @CommonsWare's suggestion (which is a good one) you can remove one line at a time or post it to a Handler that runs after your UI is displayed.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you so much for suggesting Traceview!
[getDeviceID()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10294536/2561963) was causing the lag, mainly String.toUpperCase()

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer using [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html). AsyncTask can't be slowing down the UI unless onPreExecute() or get() is called