# how multiple login is managed , when a single user try to login on many devices?

Tags: android, ios, authentication, jwt, bearer-token

I am using jwt token. when a user logged in, I save the token on the database. when the same user logged in on another device another token is saved. So when the app is uninstalled or data is cleared, each time new token is generated. so memory is used. So if there is any way to identify each device on ios. android we can identify each device using device_id or did. In ios, we don't have anything unique. Is there is any way to identify the device

Answer (score 0):

in iOS you have identifierForVendor
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor 
It is reset every time you delete all the apps from a vendor.

In Android, you can use 
[Unique ID of Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468248/unique-id-of-android-device)

Please mind that if you are mapping token with a device, the user can only be logged in one device.

Comment: @tspenzas  User can be logged in multiple devices with the same account.  Is there is any other way it can be done .

Comment: Yes but if you log out in one, it will be long out everywhere.