# Generating reliable device ID that can never change

Tags: android

I need to generate a reliable device ID. I'm using `Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID)` at the moment, but it changes after factory reset or with flashing another ROM. Could you suggest a truly hardware ID that cannot be changed?

Upd: none of the solutions suggested so far help: the suggested IDs either can change, or not always available, or both. And I definitely need it to survive reinstallation, too.

Comment: [You can find you solution here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2853253/1479570)

Comment: or here http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=1662

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115918/android-unique-id

Comment: @user370305: then it will be portable which is extremely undesirable.

Comment: Yes, But it can help for check the unique Application ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found anything better than `Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID)` so have to continue using it, despite its shortcoming.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the IMEI number like this:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String imei = tm.getDeviceId();
```

In your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

The IMEI number is guaranteed to be unique and will never change on any device.